# Static initializing block is not working as expected

Tags: java, static-initializer

I have two classes, "Test1" and "Test0", as shown in this code.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.print(Test0.randomName);
    }
}
public class Test0 {
    public static String randomName = initRandomName();
    private static String string0;
    
    static {
        string0 = "George";
    }
    private static String initRandomName() {
        return "Mr. "+string0;
    }
}
```

I thought it would print Mr. George but it printed Mr. null.
And I don't understand what's happening. Plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: Moving the assignment of `string0` before the initialization of `randomName` should fix it. A static variable can have null values and `randomName` is accessed before `string0` is even assigned a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JLS 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) details the initialization procedure. In particular:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

In other words, you can imagine your `Test0` class as being written like this:

```java
public class Test0 {
    public static String randomName;
    private static String string0;
    
    static {
        randomName = initRandomName();
        string0 = "George";
    }

    private static String initRandomName() {
        return "Mr. " + string0;
    }
}
```

So when `initRandomName()` is executed, `string0` is still null.

You *could* move the initialization of the `randomName` field to after the static initializer, like this:

```java
class Test0 {
    private static String string0;

    static {
        string0 = "George";
    }

    public static String randomName = initRandomName();

    private static String initRandomName() {
        return "Mr. "+string0;
    }
}
```

... but that's quite brittle, relying on no-one reordering the members of the class without understanding the impact.

If you really need initialization like this, I'd suggest declaring all the fields without initializing them, then initialize *everything* in the static initializer block so the ordering is obvious.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really helpful. I wanted to know how static initialization works and now I get it.